# Positioning html copyright text and payment method logos in footer

Tags: html, css

```
<!--Footer Bottom-->
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <div class="auto-container">
                <div class="inner-container">
                    <div class="copyright-text">&copy; All Right Reserved | 2023  <a href="#" style="color: #f4f5f7;">Digniverse.co</a></div>
                    <!-- Payment Logos -->
                    <div class="payment-methods">
                       <img src="images/svgs/mastercard.svg" alt="mastercard">
                       <img src="images/svgs/visacard.svg" alt="visa">
                       <img src="images/svgs/paypal.svg" alt="paypal">
                       <img src="images/svgs/bitcoin.svg" alt="bitcoin">
                       <img src="images/svgs/zelle.svg" alt="zelle">
                       <img src="images/svgs/cashapp.svg" alt="cashapp">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
.footer-bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.copyright-text {
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.payment-methods {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 50%;
}

.payment-methods img {
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .footer-bottom {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .copyright-text,
  .payment-methods {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .payment-methods {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

I created this bottom-footer html code and styled it, but it is not displaying how i want it to display. i want the copy right text to be displayed on the left side of the bottom footer and the payment method logos displayed on the right side of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.inner-container{
   display:flex;
}
.footer-bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.copyright-text {
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.payment-methods {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 50%;
}

.payment-methods img {
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .footer-bottom {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .copyright-text,
  .payment-methods {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .payment-methods {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Footer Bottom-->
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <div class="auto-container">
                <div class="inner-container">
                    <div class="copyright-text">&copy; All Right Reserved | 2023  <a href="#" style="color: #f4f5f7;">Digniverse.co</a></div>
                    <!-- Payment Logos -->
                    <div class="payment-methods">
                       <img src="images/svgs/mastercard.svg" alt="mastercard">
                       <img src="images/svgs/visacard.svg" alt="visa">
                       <img src="images/svgs/paypal.svg" alt="paypal">
                       <img src="images/svgs/bitcoin.svg" alt="bitcoin">
                       <img src="images/svgs/zelle.svg" alt="zelle">
                       <img src="images/svgs/cashapp.svg" alt="cashapp">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**inner-container class set display:flex css**

> .inner-container{
> display:flex;
> }